# Calling action from view with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a textbox and a button, when the button is clicked, i want to invoke an action from the controller and pass the textbox value as a parameter. So how can I do that?

Comment: Try reading through [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3) to start.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to do this via javascript, be that standard or more likely, jQuery.

There are many examples here on SO of this type of functionality, search for $ajax and mvc textbox value.

example:

```
$(function () {
    var txtBoxValue = $('#yourTextboxId').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("Youraction", "Yourcontroller")',
      data: { id: txtBoxValue },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
      }
    });    
});
```

**[Edit]** - depending on the usecase (which you don't specify), you could of course wrap the textbox inside a form tag and just submit it in the 'normal' fashion, thereby capturing the textbox 'name' and 'value' inside the formcollection of the action.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactely you want to do, in the ordinary cases, I suggest you make your view strongly typed (to your model), and use a form in your view. Here is an example that show you how to do it (Call the AddPerson method from the view) :

The view "AddPerson"

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Person
//You can pass in the actionName and the controllerName as parameters to the method BeginForm()
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

The action in the "Person" Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPerson(Person person)
{
    // The code
    return View("OperationEndWithSuccess");
}
```